# How to Specify PSEXEC file Copy path in remote System

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'am using the below PSEXEC switches to copy a file to remote system. By default it copies to `C:\Windows`. I have created a new folder `C:\Suba`, and the file needs to be copied to that path.

```
PsExec -f -c -d -u domain\username -p P@ssw0rd "\\10.XXX.XXX.XXX" "\\sharepath\list.exe" "C:\Suba"
```

This copies the list.exe from the share path to destination system to the path `C:\Windows`. But I need to be copied to `C:\Suba`

Thanks.

Comment: What does `psexec /?` tell you when running it from `cmd`

Comment: But regardless of that. It seems pointless to use `psexec` when you can copy directly from UNC path.

Comment: To go along with @GerhardBarnard, see also https://community.spiceworks.com/posts/1406052

Comment: I would use robocopy.  Type `help robocopy`.

Comment: Do read the [docs for psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).  You don't seem to understand how it works.